# How to set kml's icon style from bundle instead of downloading

Tags: swift, google-maps, kml, google-maps-sdk-ios

`KML` is an `XML` file that contain some GPS points with some styles that determine what color that point or line should have.

I want to set some `KML` point on `Google Map`. The `KML` file has a attribute:

```
<Icon>
        <href>http://someurl.com/Layer0_Symbol_f253d68_0_0.png</href>
</Icon>
```

to determine an `Icon` for the point. It's working well if user has Internet access.

But I need to make it working in Offline mode too.

Is there any way to make some local web service and put the `Icon` files in a `Documents` like `Apache's Document` and woking without internet connection?

Unfortunately Google Map SDK iOS doesn't have a good some documentation to determine a way to put bundle files as `KML` point `icon`

Comment: So you are looking for the directory where you can store something? That would be `let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last` which you can access with the `FileManager.default`

Comment: @Michael, no I'm looking a way to make a local webserver for my app. Or fine out a way to put some PNG files on GoogleMap instead of that default red gps marker : https://www.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/new/123fv-images/1297-google-maps-pin-icon.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: I don't think this will help with the Google Maps SDK for iOS, since it does not support KMZ files. But on other platforms, here is a good option for bundling icons in with KML files:]

An easy way to bundle an icon in with a KML file, is to combine them in a KMZ file... no need for a local web service.  KMZ is primarily a zipped (compressed) version of a KML. You can easily make a KMZ by creating a zip archive, putting a KML file inside (traditionally named doc.kml), and renaming the zip with the KMZ extension (eg: filename.kmz).

In order to include an icon file in your KMZ, you'll want to add a "files" folder in the zip archive, and put your icon image file insized that folder.  Then refer to that icon file in your KML via a relative path, for example:

```
<Icon>
  <href>files/icon.png</href>
</Icon>
```

For more info on KMZ files, check out this documentation page:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives

Comment: But, Google Map SDK Ios, do not support KMZ files.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize that. Will edit my answer to indicate that it's not a good solution on your requested platform.